# Android app using php mysql session

Tags: php, android

I am developing an android app. Backend code php and mysql.
I can register login using php myql. But I want to add profile information using android app. But the information goes as another user id.

So how to set the php session id for the whole app until logout?

Answer (score 0):

You can write PHP webservices to fetch data from database and use them in your Android app. Save the data in android app for further processes. You can generate token using webservice to keep user information or simply using user_id you can make the changes in user profile.